# jQuery - Getting href from <a>

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Q73Nd/3/

and demo here - http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/thumb/

I want to sequentially load the thumbnails and then load a bigger image of the first thumbnail above.

My problem is I can't get the `href` for the large image from the `<a>`

I have vars to the `<a>` and a imgCounter. I'm trying to use these to get the `href`

```
    console.log(link[imgCounter]).attr('href');
```

How do I get the `href` here?

Answer (score 5):

`link` is a jQuery object, `link[imgCounter]` is a DOM element.

Either use [`.eq` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the element as jQuery object

```
// jQuery object
link.eq(imgCounter).attr('href') // or .prop('href)
```

or access the DOM element's `href` property

```
// DOM element
link[imgCounter].href
```

Comment: Wow. My answer had only one different word: "collection" instead of "object". Won't submit but upvote you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should have got this error on your console

```
Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr'
```

You need to do something like this

```
console.log($(link[imgCounter]).attr('href'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Q73Nd/6/